# How to replace multiple unicode newlines with space in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want to replace all newlines and tab characters with a space in Python.

I have to handle different characters:

- Unicode new lines
- Tab
- Carriage Return (\r)

As an example, I was replacing the following characters, in nodejs like this `str.replace(/[\r\n\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028]+/g," ")`

How to do this in Python?

Comment: Did you look at the python docs for the regex module? https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily using RE in python as well:

```
import re
re.sub("\s", " ", "mystring\r\n")
```

You can change the `\s` to `\s+` if you wish to change consecutive white-space chars to a single space.

Comment: it will not work for all characters like carriage return, unicode new lines - right?

Comment: Works for anything specified as a whitespace in unicode. It includes newlines and carriage returns.

Comment: For nodejs I have to handle the unicode new lines manually. So python handles it with `\s+` automatically?

Comment: @Exploring - You can test it `re.sub(r"\s", " ", "\r\n\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028")` results in `'      '`. You can also test with `unicodedata.category()`. Anything with a Z at the front should match. `\u2028` is Zl, meaning Separator,Line. See https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode.html for unicode information.